# Create react app `npm run build` only build favicon.ico file?

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app as my boiler page.

So when i run `npm run build` on my local macbook it works fine.

But i tried to run it on my production server (Ubuntu on Digitalocean).

looks like it was only build `favicon.ico` but not the other js or even index.html

This is what happended.

```
deploy@tmdbAdmin03:/www/tmdb_admin$ sudo npm run build

> tmdb_admin@0.1.0 build /www/tmdb_admin
> ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build

Creating an optimized production build...
deploy@tmdbAdmin03:/www/tmdb_admin$ ls
README.md  build  node_modules  package.json  public  src
deploy@tmdbAdmin03:/www/tmdb_admin$ cd build
deploy@tmdbAdmin03:/www/tmdb_admin/build$ ls
favicon.ico
```

So this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmdb_admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "0.10.0",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1",
    "stylus": "0.54.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.2.3",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-pagify": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "segmentize": "^0.4.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "watch": "concurrently --names 'webpack, stylus' --prefix name 'npm run start' 'npm run styles:watch'",
    "build": "./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "styles": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus ./src/css/style.styl -o ./src/css/style.css",
    "styles:watch": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w ./src/css/style.styl -o ./src/css/style.css"
  }
}
```

So how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your machine is probably running out of memory during the build. A successful build prints a bunch of stuff after "Creating an optimized production build..."

See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1493

You can verify that this is what's happening by opening another console on the machine and running something like `watch free`.

As of Feb 11 (two days ago) an OOM should produce a non-zero exit code, so it'll actually be obvious when this kind of failure happens.